# What is the difference between firestore 'read' and 'list' security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What is the difference between using `allow list;` and `allow read;` in the Firestore access rules? More specifically, what added protection does my data get if I only allow `list` as opposed to the `read` allowance?

It seems to me that read and list provide the same security, and that he only difference is that `list` makes it a bit more cumbersome for legitimate access to singular objects. After all, a bad actor could simply list the objects and then read their full content. And if he knows the ID of the object, he can simply include it as a search term.

```
// The scopes collection is restricted to only allow 'list' requests.
// The scopes collection contains a 'postPhoto' document

// The following request will fail with an insufficient permission error, as expected
await db
  .collection(`/auth/${client}/scopes`)
  .doc('postPhoto')
  .get()
  .then(doc => console.log(doc.id, doc.data()))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))

// But this request will succeed, and it is in effect the same as the previous
await db
  .collection(`/auth/${client}/scopes`)
  .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', 'postPhoto')
  .get()
  .then(col => col.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.id, doc.data())))
  .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

I would have expected the `list` access to only allow you to see the existence of documents, but not their content. But since `list` clearly allow you access to the underlying document data as well, why not just use `read`?

Comment: It's interesting that I do not see any answer to you question yet, and could not find any somewhere else, do you know by now how they differ?

Comment: Nope. Still no answer. I would love to be able to let users query the count of a collection but not the content. Guess I'll have to do it using a separate document that always keep the count.

Answer (score 14):

Actually `list` is a specific case of `read`, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations):

> In some situations, it's useful **to break down read** and write **into more
>   granular operations**. For example, ... you may want to allow single document reads but deny large queries.
>
> A *read* rule **can be broken into** get and *list*

---

More concretely, let's take the following security rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /col1/{docId=**} {
          allow list: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }   
      match /col2/{docId=**} {
          allow get: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
  }
}
```

the following query will work:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("col1").get()
```

while this one will not work:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("col2").get()
```

---

**Now**, let's imagine each collection has a document with id "1".

the following query will work:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("col2").doc("1").get()
```

while this one will not work:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("col1").doc("1").get()
```

---

**Finally**, if you change the rule as follows, using `read`, all the above queries will work!

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /col1/{docId=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }   
      match /col2/{docId=**} {
          allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: That answers the question about the difference between 'get' and 'list', but I asked about the difference between 'read' and 'list'.

Specifically, I asked about the security difference between 'read' and 'list', since you can use a query to in effect 'get' documents protected only by 'list'.

Comment: As explained, `list` is a sub-case of `read`. My answer shows that with `read` you can list a collection of documents AND get a specific document and, on the other hand, that with `list` you can only list documents, without getting a specific document.

Comment: And that is where I think you are wrong. With `list`, you can get the content of documents, simply by doing a query instead of a simple get. E.g. 

`firebase.firestore().collection('col2').where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', '1').get().then(queryResult => console.log(queryResult.docs[0].data()))`. 

So, going back to my original question, given that `list` doesn't protect you from your users reading the content of your documents, even specific individual ones, what use is it? What is the difference (in protection) between `read` and `list`?

Comment: Good point. You probably mean `firebase.firestore().collection('col1').where(...)` but since `list` applies to **queries** and collection read requests you are able to get the content of the docs in the `queryResult`.

Comment: Ah yes, I did mean `'col1'`, the `list` protected collection. :-)

Comment: You can break `read` rules into `get` and `list` rules. Rules for `get` apply to requests for single documents, and rules for `list` apply to queries and requests for collections.

Answer (score 0):

From [Firebase Documentaion](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations):

> A `read` rule can be broken into `get` and `list`, while a `write` rule can be broken into `create`, `update`, and `delete`

The `write` rule definitions are quite clear, the difference between `get` and `list` goes as followed:

> - The get rule restricts retrieval of single documents to public documents or documents the user authored.
> - The list rule applies the same restrictions as get but for queries. It also checks the query limit, then denies any query without a limit or with a limit greater than 10.

(From [Securely query data - Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#evaluating_constraints_on_queries))

While writing rules take note that a `read` is broken into `get` and `list` - thus it can do whatever they both can in combination.

From your question,

> It seems to me that read and list provide the same security, and that he only difference is that list makes it a bit more cumbersome for legitimate access to singular objects.

`list` is used for securely querying a collection and is fired up when you call from the `collection()` method at the client side. `get` on the other hand is when you call to receive data from `doc()` method.

> After all, a bad actor could simply list the objects and then read their full content. And if he knows the ID of the object, he can simply include it as a search term.

Yup, On the flip side though, a `get` can be used to protect from collection listing queries. What looks to be a better reason for using list and get, by the Firebase Team is to make it easier writing query, instead of changing how security functions. (As of now, there [isn't a way to limit query based on where clause](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request#query), otherwise it could have been used to protect in your scenario.)

Comment: Thank you for that. But it doesn't answer the central core to my question, namely: What added protection does my data get if I only allow list as opposed to the read allowance?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, as I understood your question: If I set get to False, and use only list, my data is still exposed to single queries - right?

Comment: I want someone to show me an example ```allow read: if X;``` and an example document that is retrievable by that READ rule but which, if I change it to a ```allow list: if X```, would now be impossible to retrieve.